# Wordpress Ajax returns -1

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm currently writing a wordpress plugin and facing now a strange problem. I'm passing an ajax call to the wordpress ajax handler but it always returns -1.

So I've reduced my code for debbuging purposes but I still can't figure out whats wrong. So here's the code:

```
class Wk_Member{

 function Wk_Member() {
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_wk_member_check_username', array( $this, 'check_username' ) );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wk_member_check_username', array( $this, 'check_username') );
 }

 public function check_username( $ajax = false ) {

    if( isset( $_POST['wk_member-ajax'] ) ) {
        $ajax = true;
        echo 'test'; 
        die();
    }
}
global $wkmember;
$wkmember = new Wk_Member();
```

here's JS Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery( 'input#wk-member-registerform-usr' ).on( 'blur', function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: wk_member_frontend_settings.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action' : 'wk_member_check_username',
                'wk_member-ajax' : 'true'
            },
            success: function( returnedData ) {
                alert( returnedData );
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: actually after another hour of testing i found the problem(but i still don´t know why that was wrong). I changed the POST variable name wk_member-ajax to wk_member_ajax in the php and JS file and it worked. Seems to be a strange bug in the wordpress ajax handler or somewhere else but ok finally it works now

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anything crucially wrong that might cause the ajax request to fail ( except the missing parentheses in the provided example, but i'm guessing you are not accustomed to the SO editor ). Here is an example of what I tried to recreate the problem and everything works fine so maybe will help you to find the problem.

```
class Wk_Member {

    function Wk_Member() {
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_wk_member_check_username', array( $this, 'check_username' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wk_member_check_username', array( $this, 'check_username') );
    }

    public function check_username( $ajax = false ) {

        if( isset( $_POST['wk_member-ajax'] ) ) {           
            $ajax = true;
            echo 'test'; 
            die();
        }
    }
}

global $wkmember;
$wkmember = new Wk_Member();


add_action( 'wp_head', function() { 
?>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery( 'input#wk-member-registerform-usr' ).on( 'blur', function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
            data: {
                'action' : 'wk_member_check_username',
                'wk_member-ajax' : 'true'
            },
            success: function( returnedData ) {
                alert( returnedData );
            }
        })
    });

});
</script>


<?php
});

add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {
    return '<input type="text" id="wk-member-registerform-usr">' . $content;
});
```